# How to obtain access_token for google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytic Embed API. I want auto authorization so that user don't need to enter credential. But I am not getting how to obtain access_token.

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({    
  serverAuth: {       
    access_token: 'Server side generated token'      
  }  
});
```

Comment: You cant auto authorize with JavaScript, the user must authenticate themselves.

Comment: @DaImTo authorizing via JavaScript is perfectly fine, as long as you've obtained an access token in a secure way yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an access token you're going to have to go through the OAuth 2.0 authorization flow. You can find more details about how OAuth 2.0 works and the steps required here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: ...i have gone through OAuth 2.0 authorization flow, but i am not getting any way to obtain access token. If you know how to get it can you please share it?

Comment: The instructions in that guide explain how to get it. I'm not going to be able to explain it in a comment better than that page can.